# what is the wrong in this procedure?

Tags: sql, plsql

I want to select the latest client who has rented the car which it;s id is entered in the parameter.

this is my code:

```
create or replace procedure Q9(idcar int) as
   cursor c is 
      select client 
        from rent r 
       where r.car=idcar 
         and begindate = (select max(begindate) 
                            from rent r2 
                           where r.client=r2.client);
    clientn varchar(50);

  begin

    for k in c loop

      select clientname 
        into clientn 
        from client c 
       where c.idcl=k.client;

       dbms_output.put_line(clientn);    
    end loop;

  end;
```

Comment: Tell us, what is wrong with it? Do you get an error, or not the expected result?

Comment: @PatrickHofman , it is print out all the clients names who were rented the car, while i want to print out the latest one.

Comment: This means that the query in your cursor is returning all clients, rather than your objective of getting the client who made the latest reservation. You need to fix your cursor query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select client
from rent r
where r.car=idcar and
      begindate = (select max(begindate) from rent r2 where r.client=r2.client);
```

This gets the most recent record for each client, because of the correlated subquery.

The following gets all rentals on the biggest value of `begindate`:

```
select r.client
from rent r
where r.car = idcar and
      r.begindate = (select max(r2.begindate) from rent r2);
```

The above might return nothing.  You might need:

```
select r.client
from rent r
where r.car = idcar and
      r.begindate = (select max(r2.begindate) from rent r2 where r2.car = r.car);
```

This returns the clients who rented the car on the most recent date that the car was rented.

EDIT:

The above should work.  If you want only one value, you can do:

```
select client
from (select r.client
      from rent r
      where r.car = idcar
      order by begindate desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff , same result, it printed all clients.

Comment: @user3194430 . .  Is it possible that all clients rented that type of car on the most recent date?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes the two are working fine, thank you.